# Cannot focus specific DataGridView's Column[colAdjust] for specific record

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
  Private Sub dgvKnockOff_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgvKnockOff.CellValidating
        If bFirstLoad Then Return

        Dim currentRow As DataGridViewRow = dgvKnockOff.CurrentRow
        Dim currentRowID = dgvKnockOff.CurrentRow.Cells(colIDDgvKnockOff.Name).Value
        Dim drs As DataRow() = dtPayment.Select("id = '" & currentRowID & "'")

        If drs.Length > 0 Then
            Dim dr As DataRow = drs(0)
            If dr("chk") Then
                Dim balance = Convert.ToDecimal(dr("balance"))
                Dim adjustAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(dr("adjust_amount"))

                If balance < 0D Then
                    adjustAmt = Math.Abs(dr("balance"))
                End If
            End If
            dtPayment.AcceptChanges()
           ** dgvKnockOff.CurrentCell = dgvKnockOff.CurrentRow.Cells(colAdjust.Name)**
        End If
    End Sub
```

Help me fix this question. Based on my code, I have another cellvaluechanged event. But When I debug, I could this executes first and following by dirtyCellstateChanged, and cellvaluechanged event. Based on my logic, I need cell value changed needs to be executed first and later this should be executed. Because the cellvaluechanged holding the initial process what happens after clicking the checkbox column. Clicking checkbox column is passing balance to adjust. Cell validating validates the adjust based on balance's value. If balance is (+)ve, the cell validating event have to make it positive. And vice versa. Everything works well, but I cannot focus the column adjust with blue highlight.

Comment: You should handle the focus in the `CellValueChanged` event rather than the `CellValidating` event because `CellValidating` is meant for validation, and altering the focus within it can cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first select (cell select or row header select) selection mode in datagridview properties and use

** dgvKnockOff.Focus() **
** dgvKnockOff.Rows(row index).Cells(colAdjust.Name).Selected = True **

If this doesn't work, you can use SelectionChangedand event to select your cell by sending the row index and cell name.

dgvKnockOff.CurrentCell = dgvKnockOff(nextColumn, nextRow)

Comment: I have used the selected and it works..